# Upgraded to Cordova 1.7.0 and Xcode throws error: NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: jquery, cordova

Can't seem to figure this out.  This script worked fine with phonegap 1.2.0 and jquery 1.5.  Upgraded to Cordova 1.7.0 and Jquery 1.7.2 and can't seem to make this error go away.  My php script outputs the json perfectly, and the load-json.js script below was pulling in the data no problem.  Have no clue - would appreciate help for a 4 month newb. Thank you.

```
     Index.html:

enter code here

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/load-json.js"></script>

<script>
    function onBodyLoad() {     
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>


Javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var blogpost = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.text+'<br>'
                + item.date+'</p>';

                output.append(blogpost);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
           output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

All the plugin names have changed since about v1.6.0. Make sure you followed the upgrade steps to replace the plist with the new one.

Comment: Thanks, but not following your answer: I installed a clean copy of 1.7.0 into Xcode and started a new project from scratch. So, the plist should already have the updates?  Or not?  Can't figure this out at all.

Comment: Yes, if it was a new project you should have the correct plist. The only time I've seen this error is when the plugin name was wrong. Sorry

Comment: It's totally bizarre.  When I take out the load-json.js file, it seems to run no problem.  I wonder why the inclusion of this load-json.js file is causing issues?